# Python: Generate random integer that is not in a list

Tags: python, random

I am very new to Python (and coding in general).
I am trying to create a function which creates a duplicate of a list, with any instances of the string "rand" replaced with a random integer.
The function will be called several times, with a new input_list each time. These new items should be appended to the existing output list. We can assume there will be no repeated integers, but the "rand" string may appear many times.
This is my current code. It does very close to what I want except that when the random number is already on the list, it just moves on to the next item rather than trying to create a new random number.
Can anyone help me out with this?
Thank you in advance.

```
import random
input_list = [1, 3, "rand", 2]
def number_adder(input_list):
  output_list = []

  for item in my_list:
    if item == "rand":
      new_variable = int(random.randint(0, 4))
      if new_variable in output_list:
        continue
    else:
      new_variable = item

  output_list.append(new_variable)
return output_list
```

Comment: Can you include a specific example of an output list that is different from what you expect, and also the result you actually wanted to achieve?

Comment: _"When the function is done, it will receive a new input list. Which is then to be appended to the same output list."_ Please illustrate this in an example, as I'm not sure exactly what this means.

Comment: When you want to check for equality you should use `==` thus `if item == "rand" `.

Comment: thank you @kingJulian. I fixed it.

Comment: @RyanLague did you notice that you assign a number/string to a list (`output_list = item`)?

Comment: @glibdud I edited my question. Maybe it's more clear now?

Comment: Thank you @noamgot. It was a typo.

Comment: `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. And after fixing that: `NameError: name 'my_list' is not defined` - Why don't you test your code before asking us about it? Also, you're not calling your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

input_list = [1, 3, "rand", 2]
output_list = []

options = set(range(5))
for item in input_list:
  if item == "rand":
    new_variable = random.choice(list(options))
  else:
    new_variable = item
  output_list.append(new_variable)
  options -= set([ new_variable ])
```

You could do it like this.  But this would mean that in if no random number can be found which is possible anymore, then this will throw an exception.

This will keep a `set` of remaining options which is reduced whenever a new value is added to the output list.  Whenever a random number is needed, it will use `choice` to take a random element from that `set`.  This way you do not have to use a loop to call the random functions repeatedly until you find a valid random number.

A loop might seem feasible at first until you get to larger numbers so that you have to retry a lot until you find a valid random number (e. g. `randint(0, 100000)` in a list of 99990 elements).  This would unnecessarily slow your code down.

Actually, I'd rephrase the code a little, using a generator:

```
def fill_randoms(list_with_randoms, options):
  for item in list_with_randoms:
    value = random.choice(list(options)) if item == 'rand' else item
    yield value
    options -= set([ value ])
```

And I'd call it like this:

```
list(fill_randoms([1, 3, "rand", 2], set(range(5))))
```

But if you are not familiar with generators, stick to the other code.

Comment: Did you choose range(5) for the options variable because the list consisted of 4 items? Would len(input_list) + 1 be the same?

Comment: `random.randint(0,4)` delivers values from the set (0,1,2,3,4).  `range(5)` contains also these values.

Comment: What's the point of using a set if you convert it to a list all the time?

Comment: I want to remove values from it all the time.  Finding items in a set is cheaper than in a list because there they are hashed.  And I only have to convert it to a list because `random.choice()` is too stupid to take a `set` (which it should, really).  The main reason is: It *logically* is a set.  The values therein have no order.  To reflect that, use a `set`.

Comment: I just managed to get it working with your first version (my code is a little more complicated, getting its range from variables and don't a few other procedures before the last 2 lines and I'm a little slow at figuring this stuff out). In any case, worked like a charm!

Comment: But converting to list all the time is very expensive! Check this out, your solution takes more than twice as long as a version using a list instead: https://ideone.com/yi8WXr

Comment: @StefanPochmann You are probably right and in a production code situation I might go this way:  Code the version as it stands, then document that this version has the drawback of needing to convert a set to a list each time (due to a flaw in `random.choice`) which is expensive, check this in, then micro-optimize the part by replacing the set by a list, document this micro-optimization and check this in as well.  But I would only do this if I was sure that the expensive part was a true problem in my current usecase.  Otherwise I'd go with the cleaner code which runs slower.

Comment: Are you aware that your `.count('rand')` is a second iteration through the complete input?  That actually may be faster.  But it isn't the cleanest version I can think of.

Comment: Yeah, but that extra iteration is fast. Btw, how do you imagine `random.choice` to handle a set? With lists it's trivial, get a random index and access the value at that index. But what should it do with a set?

Comment: I don't care.  To get a single random element from a collection it should not be necessary to build a complete list out of it.  Iterate to the random-th element should be enough, for instance (still way cheaper than building a list).  I implemented that in Python as a test, there it was slower than the existing versions.  Depending on the inner workings of the set, getting an element equally distributed randomly might also be possible through some specific algorithm inherent to that kind of set.

Answer (score 1):

Loop while the number is in the output list:

```
if item == "rand": 
    new_variable = int(random.randint(0, 4))
    while new_variable in output_list:
        new_variable = int(random.randint(0, 4))
```

Comment: The `=` operator is NOT a comparison operator in Python. You need to use `==` or other existing operators if you want your code not to fail.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yeah you're right. I corrected the mistake to let it be, even if the OP seems to have his requirements.

Comment: Yeah, now it looks alright. Though I'd use `while True` and `break` to avoid the code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error pointed out in the comments.
Here are two functions that satisfy your ask:

```
import random
input_list = [1, 3, "rand", 2]

def rand_replacer(my_list):
    output_list = []
    for item in my_list:
        if item == "rand":
            while True:
                new_variable = random.randint(0, 4)
                if new_variable not in my_list:
                    output_list.append(new_variable)
                    break
        else:
            output_list.append(item)
    return output_list
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you! I will use your first function in the short term, as it is understandable with my current knowledge and also look into numpy.

Comment: The first solution will add *no* value to your output if the random number it chooses is already in the output.  I don't think that is what you want.  The second (numpy) will not check for random numbers already existing in the output list.  So both are flawed.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this now, @Alfie, and you are correct.